# How can I redirect a PHP url on an ASP ran server?

Tags: php, redirect, asp-classic

The site in question used to run on PHP files but was recently changed completely to ASP. One of their links is still being used in advertising campaigns and they want to redirect it to the new page.

old link http://example.com/videos.php
new link http://example.com/videos.asp

When I create the PHP file and use a header() redirect it doesn't function the way I would expect - instead it tried to download the .php file.

What is the best way to redirect traffic that is coming to this link?

I was thinking .htaccess but would that work?

Comment: you can use just HTML: <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://example.com/videos.asp">

Comment: @PoeHaH — Slow, inefficient, breaks the back button, don't do that … and it wouldn't work anyway since the php file would be downloaded and not treated as HTML.

Comment: It's a redirect... Why would you ever use the back button on that. 
I know it's not the best way but it works (speed is not noticeable I'd say), regarding of your server language.

Comment: A 301 code is also an option: http://www.isitebuild.com/301-redirect.htm

Comment: @PoeHaH — You are on page A. You click a link to take you to page B. B uses a client side redirect to send you to C. You click back (wanting A). You go back to B. B sends you to C. (Browsers might special case the 0 second redirect for that these days).

Answer (score 1):

You could install PHP under IIS (very easy to do) and then create a php page http://example.com/videos.php. In this page you can redirect to http://example.com/videos.asp inserting this php code only:

```
<?php
header("location: http://example.com/videos.asp");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mod_Rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to achieve that ,or [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite) if you are using IIS

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write a *rewrite rule* in your web server to rewrite requests to http://example.com/videos.php into http://example.com/videos.asp.
If you use IIS, [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/) is a tutorial about how to create a rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

> When I create the PHP file and use a header() redirect it doesn't function the way I would expect - instead it tried to download the .php file.

You need to install PHP to get that to work

> What is the best way to redirect traffic that is coming to this link?

It depends on the server

> I was thinking .htaccess but would that work?

If the server supports ASP but not PHP then it stands a good chance of being IIS which, as far as I know, does not support .htaccess files.

Comment: Can't it be installed? Php can be run under IIS. Also, if you are willing to pay $99 you can purchase ISAPI_REWRITE and work with redirects under IIS.

Answer (score -1):

Install PHP as said in the replies, then tell IIS to parse .asp files as php and just leave the urls as they are.